# spark streaming: cpp struct to kafka, kafka to spark streaming

Tags: c++, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am working with Apache Spark 2.3  and I am reading the  data from UDP port in lz0 format and decompressed that data in cpp struct using c++ code and send that struct format data to Kafka topic . after this I want to do spark streaming on Kafka data (in cpp struct format )and stored data in another Kafka topic. But I'm not able to do this or not find any API.

```
             CPP struct:
              typedef struct message{
              int id;
              char name[MAX_BUF];
              float facevalue;
              }BCASTMSG;
```

when print Kafka topic data on console then it is not in readable format.
want to cast the data.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Considering the name "apache-kafka", you can assume that its usage is complex, and you have no choice other than following the narrow way they have to offer even if it is not documented ;)

Comment: Spark can read binary data just fine. What is the issue? When you print Kafka data on console, it is UTF8, so encoded/compressed binary data wouldn't be readable of course... In any case, C++ can send directly to Kafka https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka rather than some random UDP port

Comment: I am getting data in C++ struct format in kafka and the data is not in readable form when I look into kafka. The problem is how to parse C++ struct data through spark with scala/python in real time.